# Cache image with Redis in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, caching, redis

I'm currently using Redis to serve cached content in my Laravel application. I've noticed using it with the Cache Facade is slower than with native Redis commands and [other people have noticed too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53030544/laravel-caching-with-redis-is-very-slow). I'd like to replace this snippet with one that implements the Redis facade.

```php
public function setImageCached(Request $request)
{
    $img = Cache::remember('image_'.$request->url, 6000, function () use ($request) {
        return file_get_contents($request->url);
    });
    
    return Response::make($img, 200, array('Content-Type' => 'image/jpeg'));
}
```

Comment: I think the question you are linking has this exact code (but with posts) and also converts this to using the Redis facade. Maybe try to modify that example to your own case and let us know where you are getting stuck and what you tried? Right now it sounds you want someone to just do it for you :)

Comment: This isn't how file/image caching is supposed to be done in Laravel, which may have something to do with the performance issues. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#caching

Comment: IMO, Redis is not a great fit for image caching. I'd use the filesystem driver for these.

Comment: @JasonResult check the link I posted in my first comment. You don't need to manually cache every image if you turn the filesystem caching on in config. This uses whatever the storage drivers cache method is, not Laravel's built in caching.

Comment: Oooh, yeah, my bad, that caching will only work for images stored via Laravel's filesystem drivers.. In that case, I would suggest @ceejayoz approach. You can define multiple cache drivers and use them in different situations, I would keep Redis as the default and then when store files instead of doing `Cache::remember`, use` Cache::store('file')->remember` to tell it to use the file store.

Answer (score 0):

Forming this answer off the comments, so question may need to be updated to match.

To use different cache drivers in different contexts, you can define a default cache driver (redis would be best for this) and then use a separate store for files with the following

```
Cache::store('file')->remember('image_'.$request->url, 6000, function () use ($request) {
        return file_get_contents($request->url);
});
```

This will use the filesystem driver to cache, well, files, which is a better solution that redis for this use.

One thing to note, as you have also discovered, is that Laravel doesn't clean up expired cache files. There is a package that can handle this for you `arifhp86/laravel-clear-expired-cache-file` which gives you an artisan command

```
php artisan cache:clear-expired
```

You can schedule this to run as often as you wish